# Raw data of transactions in all blocks

Tags: blockchain.info

As of April 16 2018, there have been 518563 blocks (e.g. https://blockexplorer.com/api/status?q=getBlockCount). Is anyone aware of a way to get the number of transactions in each of those 518563 blocks?

There is a page that provides the average per day of the number of transactions per block (e.g. https://blockchain.info/charts/n-transactions), but I want the raw data that went into those averages.

There is another page that provides the list of all blocks, and clicking on a block gives you the number of transactions in that block (https://blockchain.info/blocks), this is what I need, but I will have to click more than 0.5 million times.

Is anyone aware of a way to get the raw data of the number of transactions in each of all existing blocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not too difficult to count them. It tooks 5 minutes to create a script and 15 minutes to execute it. The result ia a text-file (tab-separated) with columns:

- block height
- number of transactions in block
- total transactions from the genesis
- block hash

first five lines:

```
 0  1   1   000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f
 1  1   2   00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048
 2  1   3   000000006a625f06636b8bb6ac7b960a8d03705d1ace08b1a19da3fdcc99ddbd
 3  1   4   0000000082b5015589a3fdf2d4baff403e6f0be035a5d9742c1cae6295464449
 4  1   5   000000004ebadb55ee9096c9a2f8880e09da59c0d68b1c228da88e48844a1485
```

last five lines:

```
 518413  835 310436090 0000000000000000000267cf7fecca8c6ef630bc1dfb028b3c98508b7efa3a03
 518414 1408 310437498 000000000000000000462059d45abb6364d6e5dbf9681fdba3058d50974bc760
 518415 1721 310439219 0000000000000000003c993ed7386f609a52eab8d8089c6bb125879f4c757f58
 518416 2500 310441719 00000000000000000022a1a6890682a0f5be5d13b0f5ce38eb81f40f1419ee14
 518417  662 310442381 000000000000000000162d18476f00793fb1d1e9681b29545e94bcba8beb0dd3
```

full list archive: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9PUk/iRJdzDzDE

Comment: Wow, that is impressive. Could the date be added? Also could you share the program and code you use. I think this will be very useful to many. Thank you very much amaclin.

Comment: could you share the code and how you got these data?

Answer (score 0):

This information is viewable on statoshi.info. Specifically in the [Total Historical Transactions Chart](http://statoshi.info/dashboard/db/transactions?panelId=10&fullscreen). The current transaction count (as of this writing) is 310638164 transactions.

Or you can just write a script which looks up the information for each block and calculate the total number of transactions.